# Firefox can't read my javascript confirm but on Chrome it is working

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

i have a problem on Firefox browser. I have this javascript code and it doesn't work on firefox. But in Chrome, it is working. how is that. anyone can help me?

here is my javascript code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ask = confirm('You want to update your profile');
    if (ask){
        window.location.href = 'profile.php';
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Its solved. i just delete the else code which has return. and works fine. thanks guys!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ask = confirm('You want to update your profile');
    if (ask){
        window.location.href = 'profile.php';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Comment: `return` should only be used inside functions

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console window?

Comment: Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: yes it is not working on Firefox browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `return` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ask = confirm('You want to update your profile');
    if (ask){
        window.location.href = 'profile.php';
    }
</script>
```

It looks like Chrome bug. See ECMAScript 262 12.9 section([edition 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf),[edition 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9)):

> An ECMAScript program is considered syntactically incorrect if it
>   contains a return statement that is not within a FunctionBody.

But also there is no statement that browsers(user-agents) must throw the `Syntax Error` in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

`window.location.href = 'profile.php'`

`window.location.assign("profile.php")`

You can find here a more detailed tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp